# Use subquery inside a CTE so that I can use recursion

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I need to concatenate rows of text into 1 string.  I don't want to use FOR XML PATH because I need it in plain text, not XML.
I think using a recursive CTE will do the trick but I need to use a subquery within the CTE to create the base case and the subquery table is not recognized by the recursive case in the CTE.

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @EndCreateTableScript varchar(20) = ') ON [PRIMARY] ';
DECLARE @NewLine varchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @createTableScript varchar(max)
SET @createTableScript = 'CREATE TABLE [' 


;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ScriptTbl2.RowNumber, ScriptTbl2.CreateTableStart, ScriptTbl2.ColumnScript, ScriptTbl2.EndTableScript
    FROM
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName ORDER BY TableName) AS RowNumber, TableName, 
                    CreateTableStart, ColumnTextStart + DataSizeText + ColumnNullText + @NewLine AS ColumnScript, @EndCreateTableScript + TextImageScript AS EndTableScript
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT SchemaName, TableName, @createTableScript + SchemaName + '].[' + TableName + '] ( ' + @NewLine AS CreateTableStart,
                    '[' +ColName + '] [' + DataType + '] ' AS ColumnTextStart,  
                    CASE WHEN DataType in ('bit', 'int', 'money', 'datetime') THEN ' '
                         WHEN DataType in ('numeric', 'decimal') THEN '(' + DataTypePrecision + ', ' + DataTypeScale + ') '
                         WHEN CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT) = -1 THEN '(max) '
                         WHEN DataType in ('varchar', 'varbinary') THEN '('+ DataTypeMaxLength +') '
                         WHEN DataType = 'nvarchar' THEN  '('+ CAST(CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT)/2 AS varchar(5)) +') '
                    END AS DataSizeText,    
                    CASE IsColumnNullable WHEN '0' THEN 'NOT NULL,' ELSE 'NULL,' END AS ColumnNullText,
                    CASE WHEN TextImageFileGroup IS NOT NULL THEN 'TEXTIMAGE_ON [' + TextImageFileGroup + ']' ELSE '' END AS TextImageScript                                                                                                 
                FROM #DBObjectsToAdd
            ) AS ScriptTbl
        ) AS ScriptTbl2
    WHERE RowNumber = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.RowNumber, CTE.CreateTableStart, CTE.ColumnScript + ' ' + ScriptTbl2.ColumnScript, CTE.EndTableScript 
    FROM CTE JOIN #DBObjectsToAdd ScriptTbl ON CTE.RowNumber = ScriptTbl2.RowNumber + 1
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
```

The problem is that the subquery table, ScriptTbl2 is not recognized in the recursive case.  How can I get around this problem?

The goal is to concatenate the ColumnScript text into 1 line of text for each table.

**UPDATE**
The data is not important.  I just want to concatenate multiple rows of text into 1 line.
1 Table1 Text1
2 Table1 Text2
3 Table1 Text3
4 Table2 Text4
5 Table2 Text5

Using CTE Recursion or some other type of query change to:
1 Table1 Text1 Text2 Text3
2 Table2 Text4 Text5

**UPDATE**
I created a temporary table that needs the Row_Number for the recursion and 3 text fields.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableScripts(RowNumber int, TableStart varchar(100), ColumnScript varchar(max), TableEnd varchar(100))
```

This is the `SELECT` query that adds data.

```
SELECT RowNumber, TableName, CreateTableStart, ColumnScript, TextImageScript
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName ORDER BY TableName) AS RowNumber,
                SchemaName, TableName, @createTableScript + SchemaName + '].[' + TableName + '] ( ' + @NewLine AS CreateTableStart,
        ('[' +ColName + '] [' + DataType + '] ') +  
        (CASE WHEN DataType in ('bit', 'int', 'money', 'datetime') THEN ' '
                WHEN DataType in ('numeric', 'decimal') THEN '(' + DataTypePrecision + ', ' + DataTypeScale + ') '
                WHEN CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT) = -1 THEN '(max) '
                WHEN DataType in ('varchar', 'varbinary') THEN '('+ DataTypeMaxLength +') '
                WHEN DataType = 'nvarchar' THEN  '('+ CAST(CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT)/2 AS varchar(5)) +') '
        END) +  
        (CASE IsColumnNullable WHEN '0' THEN 'NOT NULL,' ELSE 'NULL,' END) + @NewLine AS ColumnScript,
            @EndCreateTableScript + (CASE WHEN TextImageFileGroup IS NOT NULL THEN 'TEXTIMAGE_ON [' + TextImageFileGroup + ']' ELSE '' END)  AS TextImageScript                                                                                                  
    FROM #DBObjectsToAdd
) AS ScriptTbl      
ORDER BY TableName
```

For some reason, adding the `ROW_NUMBER` function to the query increases the number of rows for 1 of the tables from 2 (it only has 2 columns) to 32.

Comment: Why are you not wanting to use FOR XML here? That is the way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: The text created by XML adds those special characters when there is a new line or '<' or '>'

Comment: Could you please post table data and expected output?

Comment: The text will be an sql script that creates a table.

Comment: I added a sample of the current table data above.

Comment: @GloriaSantin I am sure this clear for you but for the rest of us this just doesn't make much sense. Your current table looks like fragments of a create table script. The query for this likely is pretty simple but we can't decipher what you are wanting to do here. Perhaps you should look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I updated my table data.  I currently have a query that returns multiple rows of text that I want to concatenate into 1 row.  The simplified example is above.  I might just have to create a temporary table and then do cte recursion.  But I wanted to see if there is a way to do it using 1 query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was just a bad reference on the JOIN in the recursive part, but that's not quite the issue.

You're referencing CTE, which can be thought of as the previous iteration of the recursion. But for your "current iteration", you're trying to reference ScriptTbl2, but ScriptTbl2 only exists within the "anchor" query - you have to redo that query with ROW_NUMBER(), etc. to build up your own ScriptTbl2 in the recursive part.

Maybe like this:

```
DECLARE @EndCreateTableScript varchar(20) = ') ON [PRIMARY] ';
DECLARE @NewLine varchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @createTableScript varchar(max)
SET @createTableScript = 'CREATE TABLE [' 


;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ScriptTbl2.RowNumber, ScriptTbl2.CreateTableStart, ScriptTbl2.ColumnScript, ScriptTbl2.EndTableScript
    FROM
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName ORDER BY TableName) AS RowNumber, TableName, 
                    CreateTableStart, ColumnTextStart + DataSizeText + ColumnNullText + @NewLine AS ColumnScript, @EndCreateTableScript + TextImageScript AS EndTableScript
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT SchemaName, TableName, @createTableScript + SchemaName + '].[' + TableName + '] ( ' + @NewLine AS CreateTableStart,
                    '[' +ColName + '] [' + DataType + '] ' AS ColumnTextStart,  
                    CASE WHEN DataType in ('bit', 'int', 'money', 'datetime') THEN ' '
                         WHEN DataType in ('numeric', 'decimal') THEN '(' + DataTypePrecision + ', ' + DataTypeScale + ') '
                         WHEN CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT) = -1 THEN '(max) '
                         WHEN DataType in ('varchar', 'varbinary') THEN '('+ DataTypeMaxLength +') '
                         WHEN DataType = 'nvarchar' THEN  '('+ CAST(CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT)/2 AS varchar(5)) +') '
                    END AS DataSizeText,    
                    CASE IsColumnNullable WHEN '0' THEN 'NOT NULL,' ELSE 'NULL,' END AS ColumnNullText,
                    CASE WHEN TextImageFileGroup IS NOT NULL THEN 'TEXTIMAGE_ON [' + TextImageFileGroup + ']' ELSE '' END AS TextImageScript                                                                                                 
                FROM #DBObjectsToAdd
            ) AS ScriptTbl
        ) AS ScriptTbl2
    WHERE RowNumber = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.RowNumber, CTE.CreateTableStart, CTE.ColumnScript + ' ' + ScriptTbl2.ColumnScript, CTE.EndTableScript 
    FROM CTE JOIN (
        SELECT ScriptTbl2.RowNumber, ScriptTbl2.CreateTableStart, ScriptTbl2.ColumnScript, ScriptTbl2.EndTableScript
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName ORDER BY TableName) AS RowNumber, TableName, 
                    CreateTableStart, ColumnTextStart + DataSizeText + ColumnNullText + @NewLine AS ColumnScript, @EndCreateTableScript + TextImageScript AS EndTableScript
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT SchemaName, TableName, @createTableScript + SchemaName + '].[' + TableName + '] ( ' + @NewLine AS CreateTableStart,
                    '[' +ColName + '] [' + DataType + '] ' AS ColumnTextStart,  
                    CASE WHEN DataType in ('bit', 'int', 'money', 'datetime') THEN ' '
                         WHEN DataType in ('numeric', 'decimal') THEN '(' + DataTypePrecision + ', ' + DataTypeScale + ') '
                         WHEN CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT) = -1 THEN '(max) '
                         WHEN DataType in ('varchar', 'varbinary') THEN '('+ DataTypeMaxLength +') '
                         WHEN DataType = 'nvarchar' THEN  '('+ CAST(CAST(DataTypeMaxLength AS INT)/2 AS varchar(5)) +') '
                    END AS DataSizeText,    
                    CASE IsColumnNullable WHEN '0' THEN 'NOT NULL,' ELSE 'NULL,' END AS ColumnNullText,
                    CASE WHEN TextImageFileGroup IS NOT NULL THEN 'TEXTIMAGE_ON [' + TextImageFileGroup + ']' ELSE '' END AS TextImageScript                                                                                                 
                FROM #DBObjectsToAdd
            ) AS ScriptTbl
        ) AS ScriptTbl2
    ) AS ScriptTbl3
    ON ScriptTbl3.RowNumber = CTE.RowNumber + 1 --you want each iteration to increase, right?
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Comment: When I do the change, the `RowNumber` cannot resolve because it does not exist and `ScriptTbl2` does not exist in the `SELECT`

Comment: @GloriaSantin answer completely updated, see if that helps any

Comment: of course you can refactor the common query into a view, etc. but trying to reuse the anchor query is the immediate thing to fix, i think

Comment: I am getting an error that i can't use `DISTINCT` in the CTE.  It does not make sense.

Comment: I created a temporary table of the anchor data. So, that the temp table contains 3 text fields.  The StartScriptText, ColumnText, EndScriptText.  I need to add the RowNumber to the temp table but when I do that for some reason one of the tables returns 32 rows of redundant data.  It should only have 2 rows of data.

Comment: so your original problem is fixed, right?  if you're debugging follow-on steps, please post the relevant code (enough to build your temp table #, or a permanent version of it).  As is, it *could* be as simple as the value of the TableName column, but we don't know so how can we help?

Comment: I believe by creating a temp table.  It will fix the problem.

Comment: Sounds good.  Did my answer help you with your original problem? Would you like to mark it as the answer? :)